# Cannot properly configure PayPal Sandbox

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I'm attempting to enable PayPal as a payment provider on our website and test some transactions, however I cannot get the PayPal sandbox to work. I configure the sandbox with the correct URL:

https://sandbox.paypal.com/

However, when I go back in to the payment process to verify the settings, it has always reverted back to the same as production:

https://www.paypal.com/

Why can't I get CiviCRM to keep the sandbox settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've found a bug. I just confirmed that if on 4.7.8 - you have - under Processor Details for Test Payments:

[image]

And then hit Save = you end up with [for the very same Processor Details for Test Payments]:

[image]

Go ahead and file this on JIRA: http://issues.civicrm.org - not sure why those settings are not retained. They certainly used to be completely functional.

In the mean time I'd recommend run some Live Tests - with real easy to spot $ ($1.11, $2.22 etc).

Comment: And fixed as of 4.7.9